# Pretty print CSV with many columns with each row as a table

Tags: shell, csv

I have a very large CSV with ~50 columns like the follows:

```
A,B,C,...,Z
v1,,v3,...,v26
w1,w2,w3,...,w26
```

I want to display it in console, but tools like `column -t` doesn't work because each line is too long and wraps, making it unable to be read.

My goal is to display it row by row, with each row displayed as a table like `<ColumnName> | <Value>`:

```
----------
A |  v1
B |  
C |  v3
...
Z |  v26
----------
<blank line>
----------
A |  w1
B |  w2
...
Z |  w26
----------
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `column` doesn't work as described in the description. Python's pandas also doesn't seem to work. So far awk seems most viable, but I haven't tried it by myself

Comment: Okay, but it's not that hard, see [this draft](https://ideone.com/3KWoOj), I think you can take it from there and make exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR == 1 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) h[i] = $i; next }
           { print "----------"
             for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s | %s\n", h[i], $i
             print "----------\n"
           }' input.csv
----------
A | v1
B |
C | v3
... | ...
Z | v26
----------

----------
A | w1
B | w2
C | w3
... | ...
Z | w26
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

You must disable word wrap and you can use `column` in this way

```
<input column -t -s, | less
```